# Returning a mock from casting operation, Mockito, Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have this code here that I am trying to test:

```
public class Something {
    public String doSomething(MyClass myClass) { 
        return Utils.getPresentationString(myClass)
    }
}

public class Utils{
    public static String getPresentationString(MyClass myClass) {
        if (myClass instanceof MySubClass) {
            MySubClass mySubClass = (MySubClass) myClass;
            return mySubClass.getMaskedPresentationString();
        } else {
            return myClass.getPresentationString();
        }
    }
}
```

Because Utils is static, I am testing it in a black box manner while testing the Something class.

I am trying to have this line of code return a mock:

```
MySubClass mySubClass = (MySubClass) myClass;
```

So I can do

```
doReturn(MY_MASKED_STRING).when(this.mySubClassMock).getMaskedPresentationString()
```

and then do

```
assertEquals(MY_MASKED_STRING, this.somethingUnderTest.doSomething(this.myClassMock))
```

How do I do something like this work

```
doReturn(this.mySubClassMock).when(this.myClassMock).<<cast to MySubClass.class>>
```

Comment: Why don't you just override `getPresentationString()` in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is a cast, it can't return what isn't already there. But then.

```
public static String getPresentationString(MyClass myClass) {
    if (myClass instanceof MySubClass) {
```

that is simply the object coming into that class.

Thus you simply need:

```
MySubClass subclassMock = mock(MySubClass.class);
...

objectUnderTest.getPresentationString(subclassMock);
```

And then your production code should gladly go "it is an instanceof", and then cast, giving you full control over that incoming object.

But note: the "real" OOP way here: avoid that instanceof/cast!

```
return mySubClass.getMaskedPresentationString();
... else
return myClass.getPresentationString()
```

Why does your SubClass not *override* `getPresentationString()`, to return that other value? If that would be wrong, would it be possible to have some "base" abstract method that then has two implementations?!

Long story short:

- the direct answer is: simply pass in something that is either `mock(MyClass.class)` or `mock(MySubClass.class)`, depending on which path you intend to test
- but much better: get rid of that instanceof/cast part altogether. The whole point of good OOP is to exactly avoid such code!

Comment: You are right, Never realised I could just use the mySubClassMock directly, and you are right also for the cast and the instanceof, but since this is already in production and my task is to unit test it, I can't change it unless I go through a code review and an audit.

Comment: @Sebastien You are what you decide to be. Consider yourself the Omega Sector, the last line of defense (https://www.behance.net/gallery/20584263/Omega-Sector-the-last-line-of-defense). You are the gatekeeper, the one who gets to reward the diligent workers, and to rip apart the lazy ones, too. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is a compile-time check, it does not matter during run-time.

Just pass a mocked instance of `MySubClass` that you have configured with proper stubbing.